# Why does Conway state $\partial\sigma(a)=\sigma(a)$ when $a$ is a Hermitian element of a $\mathcal{C}^\ast$-algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Here is the offending proof:

> **$\bf 1.14.$ Proposition.** *Let $\scr A$ and $\scr B$ be $C^*$-algebras with a common identity and norm such that $\scr A\subseteq \scr B$. If $a\in\scr A$, then $\sigma_{\scr A}(a)=\sigma_{\scr B}(a)$.*
>
> $\rm P\scriptstyle{ROOF}$ First assume that $a$ is hermitian and let ${\scr C}=C^* (a)$, the $C^*$-algebra generated by $a$ and $1$. So $\scr C$ is abelian. By Corollary 1.13 $\sigma_{\scr C}(a)\subseteq \Bbb R$. By Theorem VII.5.4, $\sigma_{\scr A}(a)\subseteq\sigma_{\scr C}(a)=\partial\sigma_{\scr C}(a)\subseteq\sigma_{\scr A}(a)$; so $\sigma_{\scr A}(a)=\sigma_{\scr C}(a)\subseteq\Bbb R$. By similar reasoning, $\sigma_{\scr B}(a)=\sigma_{\scr C}(a)$, and hence $\sigma_{\scr A}(a)=\sigma_{\scr B}(a)$.
>
> $\quad$ Now let $a$ be arbitrary. It suffices to show that if $a$ is invertible in $\scr B$, $a$ is invertible in $\scr A$. So suppose there is a $b$ in $\scr B$ such that $ab=ba=1$. Thus, $(a^*a)(bb^*)=(bb^*)(a^* a)=1$. Since $a^* a$ is hermitian, the first part of the proof implies $a^* a$ is invertible in $\scr A$. But inverses are unique, so $bb^*=(a^* a)^{-1}\in\scr A$. Hence $b=b(b^*a^*)=(bb^*)a^*\in\scr A$.

In that inclusion chain, in the middle, we have:

$$\sigma_{\mathcal{C}}(a)=\partial\sigma_{\mathcal{C}}(a).$$

The question obviously is: what does $\partial$ mean? To me, it means the boundary, which, in my book, is the set of points which are limit points for both the set and the complement. So this equality is stating that all points of $\sigma_{\mathcal{C}}(a)$ are limit points both for that spectrum and its complement. And then the question is: how is that proven? I do know that, since $a$ is hermitian in that part, the spectrum is real. But that only guarantees that all its points are limit points for its complement. Of course, I might have misinterpreted $\partial$. So why is this equality true? Is there a proof (maybe somewhere in Conway), or is it just that $\partial$ indicates the limit points of the complement, and not what I call boundary and denote with $\partial$?

Comment: It might seem a dumb question, but have you tried looking in Conway's book, for a definition of $\partial$?

Comment: @b00nheT I looked for _boundary_ and found nothing related. I thought looking for the symbol $\partial$ would probably have been too long.

Comment: That is what I thought... but look in the index, often frequent used symbols are listed with names (and descriptions)... but I cannot guarantee, as I do not know this book

Comment: The unicode symbol ∂ is not found via searching.

Comment: Good piece of advice @b00nheT, I had no idea there was a symbols list at the end. Which unfortunately doesn't show $\partial$…

Comment: The topological boundary of sets behaves like $\partial A^\complement=\partial A = (int A\cup int A^\complement)^\complement$. E.g. a closed line segment on the plane is indeed the boundary of itself.

Comment: I perfectly agree that a line is its own boundary @Berci. But if I take my definition of boundary and a single point, then it has empty boundary. With your definition, though, it becomes its own boundary. So maybe it is my definition of boundary (boundary of $A$ is the set of points that arr limit points for both $A$ and $A^C$) that is to be questioned.

Comment: Also using your definition @MickG, you would indeed get the same boudary... you can most definitely check it out using the standard metric

Comment: @b00nheT if $x$ is an isolated point of $A$, then it is not in the interior of $A$, and most definitely not in that of $A^C$, implying it lies on the boundary, Berci's.definition. But such a point is not a limit point of $A$, so it cannot line on my boundary, for then it would have to be both a l.p. of $A^C$ (which it obviously is) AND of $A$ (which, as said above, it obviously is not). So those two do not coincide in general. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Well.. your definition can agree with mine if '*limit point*' of $A$ is meant as e.g. $\exists a_n\in A:\ a_n\to a$, i.e. *not excluding isolated points*. Alternatively, $\partial A=cl A\cap cl A^\complement$.

Comment: You are missing something.  The boundary $\partial A$ of $A$ is not the intersection of the sets of limit points of $A$ and $A^c$, it is the intersection of the closures of $A$ and $A^c$.  In particular if $A$ is a closed set (which is the case here, as the spectrum is always closed), the boundary is the set of points of $A$ that are limit points of $A^c$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael that would be the fault of my Analysis 1 book which defines the boundary as I said. As Berci noted, the only problem are isolated poins of either $A$ or the complement, which lie in both closures but in neither set of limit points, taking _l.p._ of a set as points $x$ such that every neighborhood intersects $A$ in at least one point that is not $x$ itself. I will check if my book defined l.p. that way or without the "that is not $x$ itself" part.

Comment: Seems I just misremembered the definition. I opened the book and it defines _boundary point for $A$_ as a point for which for all $r$ we have $B(p,r)\cap A\neq\varnothing$, thereby including i.p.s. But it is the drawing below the definition that I had memorized and that shows a nice ellipse which has no isolated points and marks a boundary point which, of course, is in my erroneous definition of boundary. So all of this is entirely my memory's fault :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\c{\complement}
\def\cl{\mathrm{cl}\,}$
Taking this definition: $\partial A:=\cl A\cap \cl A^\c$, the spectrum $A:=\sigma(a)$ is closed, and its complement is dense as misses at most parts of the real line. 
This proves $\sigma(a)=\partial\sigma(a)$.

Comment: $\operatorname{cl}$ meaning _closure of_, I take it. I usually denote closure with an overline, so the $\operatorname{cl}$ notation is new to me -- and was btw another mysterious symbol in Conway :).